# what kind of string is split by the ^ regex

Tags: java, regex

If I have split statement like

```
String array1[]= test.split("^");
```

what could be the possible test string value such that this ("^") regex will split the test string?

I am aware that The ^ is a special character in Java regex - it means "match the beginning" of an input.

Comment: I think there would be 1 element as a result.

Comment: What makes you think that there is a string that can be split by it?

Comment: @Ivar I found somewhere that has split with caret as regex in it. so Does this statement never split any string?

Comment: I'm tempted to say no, but I've seen weirder stuff. The only think I could possibly imagine would be newlines or a null-character, but both also result in one result. Maybe the code you seen is wrong? It tried to split by a literal `^`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what could be the possible test string value such that this ("^") regex will split the test string?

`^` matches the beginning of a line in Java.

According to the Pattern [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> By default, the regular expressions `^` and `$` ignore line terminators and only match at the beginning and the end, respectively, of the entire input sequence. **If `MULTILINE` mode is activated then `^` matches at the beginning of input and after any line terminator except at the end of input.** When in `MULTILINE` mode `$` matches just before a line terminator or the end of the input sequence. (Emphasis, mine)

Therefore, the following code will produce the output below:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^", Pattern.MULTILINE);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pattern.split("Test\nTest")));
```

Output:

```
[Test
, Test]
```

As you can see, the `String` has been split successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will not "split" any string, and instead just match the very first character of any string, making the array length 1 with only the original string inside.

This is the code I used for testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String[]> allArrays = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] a1 = "afeafwewa".split("^");
        String[] a2 = "   fwaefawwa   ".split("^");
        String[] a3 = "fawef feawf a".split("^");
        String[] a4 = "L feawf :::".split("^");
        String[] a5 = "awefawefafewf     \\\\\\".split("^");
        String[] a6 = "\"".split("^");
        String[] a7 = "\\".split("^");

        allArrays.add(a1);
        allArrays.add(a2);
        allArrays.add(a3);
        allArrays.add(a4);
        allArrays.add(a5);
        allArrays.add(a6);
        allArrays.add(a7);

        allArrays.forEach(strings -> System.out.println(strings.length + " : " + strings[0]));
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
1 : afeafwewa
1 :    fwaefawwa   
1 : fawef feawf a
1 : L feawf :::
1 : awefawefafewf     \\\
1 : "
1 : \
```

This confirms that the entire string is matched, and that no splitting occurs.

Note: I have tested this with other strings as well, but I didn't paste them all in this code.